# STL thrust multiple vector transform?

Tags: c++, stl, cuda, thrust

I was wondering if there was a more efficient way of writing a = a + b + c?

```
 thrust::transform(b.begin(), b.end(), c.begin(), b.begin(), thrust::plus<int>());
 thrust::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), a.begin(), thrust::plus<int>());
```

This works but is there a way to get the same effect using just one line of code?
I looked at the saxpy implementation in the examples, however this uses 2 vectors and a constant value;

---

Is this more efficient?

```
struct arbitrary_functor
{
    template <typename Tuple>
    __host__ __device__
    void operator()(Tuple t)
    {
        // D[i] = A[i] + B[i] + C[i];
        thrust::get<3>(t) = thrust::get<0>(t) + thrust::get<1>(t) + thrust::get<2>(t);
    }
};


int main(){

     // allocate storage
    thrust::host_vector<int> A;
    thrust::host_vector<int> B;
    thrust::host_vector<int> C;

    // initialize input vectors
    A.push_back(10);
    B.push_back(10);
    C.push_back(10);

    // apply the transformation
    thrust::for_each(thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(A.begin(), B.begin(), C.begin(), A.begin())),
                     thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(A.end(),   B.end(),   C.end(),   A.end())),
                     arbitrary_functor());

    // print the output
       std::cout << A[0] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This looks pretty good to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`a = a + b + c` has low arithmetic intensity (only two arithmetic operations for every 4 memory operations), so the computation is going to be memory bandwidth bound.  To compare the efficiency of your proposed solutions, we need to measure their bandwidth demands.

Each call to `transform` in the first solution requires two loads and one store for each call to `plus`.  So we can model the cost of each `transform` call as `3N`, where `N` is the size of the vectors `a`, `b`, and `c`. Since there are two invocations of `transform`, the cost of this solution is `6N`.

We can model the cost of the second solution in the same way. Each invocation of `arbitrary_functor` requires three loads and one store. So a cost model for this solution would be `4N`, which implies that the `for_each` solution should be more efficient than calling `transform` twice. When `N` is large, the second solution should perform `6N/4N = 1.5x` faster than the first.

Of course, you could always combine `zip_iterator` with `transform` in a similar way to avoid two separate calls to `transform`.

Comment: That is a very elegant analysis, but I can't help wondering about how expensive the zip iterator is (I use it a lot, but I have no feel for what how it works or its performance). Does that have any impact here?

Comment: zip_iterator can indeed increase a kernel's footprint, as each zipped iterator requires register resources. In this example, A is included in the zip redundantly -- once as a source, and once as a destination. A slightly more lean solution might only send it in the zip once, but it's unlikely to make a difference given that arbitary_functor is so simple.